# Website looks fine in other browsers except IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

On my [home page](http://www.heatherkirk.net) I have my work listed in three row columns. It looks absolutely fine on every browser except for Internet Explorer. In IE, the row that is on the left is supposed to be in the middle, and the one that is below the rows is where the leftmost row is supposed to be. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'd float sidenav left and float pieces right and give pieces a width equivalent to the width of it's content (the three columns).

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is a little messed up, it's probably why Internet Explorer is having problems with it.  You've got two `<div>` tags with the same id (`row2`). I think this is the one that IE displays that other browsers don't which is messing up your columns.

Looks like you copy and pasted a section of code twice.

This looks to be the extra code:

```
<a title="Angry Walk Cycle - Made in Maya" href="http://vimeo.com/43512708" rel="prettyPhoto">

        <div id="row2">
        <ul> 
        <li class="notactive"></li></ul></div></a>
```

Deleting this out of your code gets it to show up correctly in IE 9 for me.

Comment: hello, I'm sorry for being a pain! But I'm looking through my code at the moment and I don't see any repeat of row2. Here is my code, I will leave out the descriptions and links to make it easier to look through. 

  <li class="active"><a href="" /> </li>
        </ul>
         </div> ( this is from row1, just to clarify!)
        
        <div id="row2">
        <ul> 
        <li class="notactive"><a href="" /></a> </li>
        <li class="notactive"> <a href="" /> </a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="" /></a> </li>
        </ul>
    
        </div>

Comment: Looks like you fixed it.  IE now looks fine and the HTML is no longer messed up :) (well it was fixed when I first wrote this, but now column 1 is missing...)

Comment: Haha, I just fixed it. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem, feel free to click the answer button.